# When beside launch will android.intent.action.MAIN be fired by Android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, launch

If an Activity has the following filter:

```
 <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />  
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
 </intent-filter>
```

Under what circumstances will an Intent matching the above filter be issued by Android?

1)  During launch of the application.

2) ?  Are there any other circumstances?

Answer (score 1):

Anything can use that filter. The OS never uses that filter, AFAIK. Home screen applications typically use that filter. Other applications can use that filter if they so choose -- for example, [here is a sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Introspection/Launchalot) that creates its own launcher-style list.

Comment: I'm trying to keep that application that contains my widget provider from coming to the foreground with this MAIN activity.  I can't get rid of it because I need to also be able to launch the application